# C keyword interruptions

Tags: c

Let's take two examples of having 'stuff' between a keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("OK\n");
    pri\
ntf("OK\n");             // version 1
    pri/**/ntf("Hi");    // version 2
    return 0;
}
```

That is, having a comment `/* ... */` and a `\/n`. How are these two supposed to be treated, or is it compiler dependent?

Comment: That is not valid.

Comment: @suriyel right, yes it doesn't compile. I'm just wondering what the rules are for replacing comments and newlines in the preprocessor before compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C99 [translation phases](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.1.1.2):

> The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by the following phases.
>
> 1. Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation- defined manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. Trigraph sequences are replaced by corresponding single-character internal representations.
> 2. Each instance of a ***backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines***. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.
> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. ***Each comment is replaced by one space character.*** New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.
> 4. [...]

```
    pri\
ntf("OK\n");             // version 1
```

Valid, since it parses as `printf("OK\n");` after step 2 above.

```
    pri/**/ntf("Hi");    // version 2
```

Invalid, since it parses as `pri ntf("Hi");` after step 3 above.

Comment: I wonder why never understood way an end-of-line backslash was required to be immediately followed by a newline without trailing whitespace, when some text file formats don't distinguish between lines that do or don't have trailing whitespace.  If white space after a trailing backslash was allowed, then there would be no need to worry about whether fixed-length records get imported with or without whitespace padding, since trailing whitespace would not be significant in any other context.

Comment: @supercat Guess there must be some historical reason, like with other C quirks, but I never figured out what this reason in particular might have been. This was a real concern in the far past when certain editors better left unnamed would sometimes append blanks at the end of lines during what they called virtual space navigation.

Comment: @supercat The backslash escapes the **immediately following** character. If it is a newline, it means that we humans want to see a line break but the compiler should not. If it is no newline, the next character is escaped, with another meaning. -- Your question should rather be "_Why does my text tool (aka editor) not distinguish these cases? Why does it not show me the whitespace?_" And you will change your preferences... -- If there is a meaning in character sequences, tools to produce them must obey them. If you want fixed-length, insert needed whitespace before the backslash / last token.

Comment: @thebusybee: Some systems store text files as blank-padded fixed length records.  Punched cards couldn't accommodate the C character set (including such essential features as lowercase letters) but EBCDIC-based systems which were derived from those used with punched cards could.  On such systems, there is no "new line" character, but one is inferred at the end of each record.  As for the backslash "escaping the next character", it is routinely used to escape a sequence.  Just as `\x` would attempt to escape succeeding characters from the set [0-9A-Fa-f], , there would be no...

Comment: ...conceptual problem with inviting implementations to interpret a backslash followed by a non-newline whitespace as escaping everything up through the next newline (squawking if it encounters anything other than whitespace).  One of the reasons for giving newline splices priority treatment was to allow for the possibility of an automated tool converting a source file that contains long source lines for use on a system which uses e.g. fixed 72- or 80-character records, so it has unusual rules which differ from those of backslashes in other contexts.

Comment: @thebusybee: For example, it's possible for a line-splice backslash to appear in the middle of another backslash escape.  If, for example, one line ends with `macro(\6\` and the next line starts with `100)`, and the macro stringizes its argument, the argument will stringize as `"h0"`.  Perhaps the idea is to allow an implementation to know whether a backslash needs to be dropped as a line splice, but that objective would be achieved if backslash immediately followed by whitespace couldn't be anything else.

Comment: @supercat Do you have a citation for your claim on fixed-length records? -- The interpretation of backslash plus newline is done by the preprocessor, all other by the compiler AFAIK. Even though both were developed in parallel and probably the first to support the second, they are still separated tools with their own language. -- I never found this combination in the context you say, and I'm using C since the early 80s in several professional environments. It was always used to make source lines readable for humans. But my view is probably limited, and still I'm eager to learn.

Comment: @thebusybee: I've worked with an OS/360-based system which used fixed-length records, and from what I understand one of the goals of the C Standard was to make the language usable on that platform (I never programmed C on that platform--just PL/I).

Comment: @supercat Thanks! And what was the reason to put the backslash not in the last column if a line needed continuation? Seems to be the most simple solution. (But we are getting OT...)

Answer (score 3):

I save the code in file a.cpp,
then pre-compile the code:

```
gcc -E a.cpp
```

The output is:

```c
int main(void)
{
    printf("OK\n");
    printf("OK\n");

    pri ntf("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

The first case can pass the compile. but for the second case, gcc will replace `/**/` to blank, then compile will fail.

gcc and clang have the same result on this. It's a C standard.

Comment: compliler works in 3 stage : pre-compile, compile, link. -E is pre-compile

Comment: @David542 it means only preprocess but don't compile https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Evde36